# postgres setup in Mac

Tags: postgresql, macos

My client gave me a link like following:

> postgres://somestring:someotherstring@ec2-54-246-.....eu-west1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/somedatabasename...

And he  told me here is your PostgreSQL database link, but when I clicked on that link, it went to my default email app TO: field. When I told my client  about it he was telling me "Are you kidding me".

So it is my Mac settings problem with PostgreSQL?

Comment: You need proper client software to connect to this db. Use [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org) for example. Also - I hope you're joking.

Comment: I installed pgAdmin but same issue

Comment: Use information in the link to create new database connection inside pgAdmin. Do not click on the link.

Comment: You don't seem to know how to use a database connection string then. You can't click on that, you have to parse it out to username, password, host, port, and database name.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a client, and not the database on macOS, you can install libpq using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/). (I see you're using AWS for example)

```
brew install libpq
```

Then you symlink all the tools:

```
brew link --force libpq
```

After that, you can use the psql client, the native PostgreSQL client, and connect like:

```
psql -U somestring -h c2-54-246-.....eu-west1.compute.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -d somedatabasename -W
```

It will prompt you for the database password. Just enter the password you got from that connection string, which you put as `someotherstring`.